# Jquery UI date-picker Set default date

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I used jQuery UI for datepicker i want to show current date in the field as default following is my code please help

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
         $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        currentText: "Now"
         });

        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        currentText: "Now"
        });

    });
        </script>

From Date: <input type='text' id='datepicker' name='date_from' />
To Date:   <input type='text' id='datepicker2' name='date_to' />
```

But I could not set default date

Comment: Try `var date_today = new Date();` Then use `defaultDate: date_today`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829033/jquery-ui-datepicker-default-date . Try to search before posting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        }).val(getTodaysDate(0)); // For current date

        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            }).val(getTodaysDate(1));  // For previous month's date
    });

  function getTodaysDate (val) {
    var t = new Date, day, month, year = t.getFullYear();
    if (t.getDate() < 10) {
        day = "0" + t.getDate();
    }
    else {
        day = t.getDate();
    }
    if ((t.getMonth() + 1) < 10) {
        month = "0" + (t.getMonth() + 1 - val);
    }
    else {
        month = t.getMonth() + 1 - val;
    }

    return (day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this works fine, i want 1 more help  in the 1st datepicker i want show 1 month previous date from today

Answer (score 0):

you can use [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", (new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: new Date()
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set value like this.

```
$("#datepicker").val() = 'some value';
```

Write a condition if there is no value use above or use its value.