# Default value for jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some questions regarding jQuery UI date picker.

1 - Is there an option to have a default value? What I am trying to do is pre-filled my input text type with today's date.

2 - If I put the type = "Date" instead of type = "Text" and then use jquery time picker on it, I get this error when I select the date.

```
 The specified value '02/18/2015' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd.'
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> To create the date picker and set the date. You can assign today's date by 'new Date().' You can set input `type=text` or `type=date`.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
     }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: What if I want type = "Date" ?

Comment: Yes I can set it but when I select the value it is not selected. Check the console. I am trying it on chrome.

Comment: Yes, you are right `date` type not working in `chrome` so you have to change `text`.

Comment: If you want work with `type=date` then might this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890376/chrome-type-date-and-jquery-ui-date-picker-clashing

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {

  $(".dp").datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: ''
  }).on("show", function() {
    $(this).val(new Date()).datepicker('update');
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer Below one: It works fine for me.

[Jquery UI date-picker Set default date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229473/jquery-ui-date-picker-set-default-date)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        }).val(getTodaysDate(0)); // For current date

        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            }).val(getTodaysDate(1));  // For previous month's date
    });

  function getTodaysDate (val) {
    var t = new Date, day, month, year = t.getFullYear();
    if (t.getDate() < 10) {
        day = "0" + t.getDate();
    }
    else {
        day = t.getDate();
    }
    if ((t.getMonth() + 1) < 10) {
        month = "0" + (t.getMonth() + 1 - val);
    }
    else {
        month = t.getMonth() + 1 - val;
    }

    return (day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
   }
</script>
```