# Conflict with DatePicker and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So far, my app has been working ok with this until today. What I've been doing is the following:

```
  <input type="date" ng-model="startDate.value" />
```

And in my .js code, I have this:

```
$scope.startDate = {
        value: new Date()
    };
```

It's been working fine until today, that the console shows this warning:

```
The specified value "Thu Mar 10 2016 15:20:19 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
```

I pretty sure that I haven't change anything, it was working perfectly, showing today's date as default value, but now it gives that warning and as default it only shows `dd/mm/aaaa`

Did I change something? I updated my bower, but I'm pretty sure that it has nothing to do with that...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried type="text" instead of type="date"?

On UI-Bootstrap page, their examples show `<input type="text" ...`

Related posts:
[Default value for jquery date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604379/default-value-for-jquery-date-picker)