# set the current date as the default early in my datepicker so that I can filter the data according to the current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, submit, daterangepicker

I have daterangepicker from [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_date_range_picker_with_jquery_ui_archived/)
You can see the javascrpt and css in: http://jsfiddle.net/CUMFw/

I have try to show set default date from this solution([jQuery-UI datepicker default date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829033/jquery-ui-datepicker-default-date) & [How do I pre-populate a jQuery Datepicker textbox with today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date)) but still not work.

this my partially experiment php code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.daterangepicker.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" type="text/css"title="ui-theme" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
     $('#tgl').daterangepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        arrows:true,
        onChange: function(){
           $('#frmDate').submit()
        },
     });
});
</script>
<?php 
$dates = explode("-",$_POST[tgl] );
$date1=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[0]));
if ($dates[0] == $_POST[tgl]){
    $date2 = $date1;
    echo $date2;
}
else{
$date2=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[1]));}
?>
<form id="frmDate" action="http://localhost/job/uadmin.php?page=absensi" method="post">
<input id="tgl" name="tgl" type="text" class="field"  value="<?php echo $_POST[tgl]; ?>"/>
</form>
```

Please help me out from my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I'd try. First, make sure you have a link to jQuery above your script block. Use either Google's or a local copy:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If that doesn't work, next try replacing all instances of `$` in your Javascript code with `jQuery`:

```
jQuery(function(){ 
 jQuery('#tgl').daterangepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    arrows:true,
    onChange: function(){
       jQuery('#frmDate').submit()
    },
 });
});
```

This can help avoid conflicts with other libraries that also use `$` as a variable.

Comment: hi musical_coder, thanks for your respons. it turns out I already have jquery.min.js and jquery.UI.min.js. I have edit my question. And then i have change `$` with `JQuery` but still not work.

Comment: Try going back to basics then. Replace the inside of the jQuery block with this: `jQuery('#tgl').daterangepicker({arrows: true, dateFormat: 'M d, yy'});`, which I borrowed from the source code of demo page for Date Range Picker. When you do that, does it at least show the range picker, minus today's date?

Comment: Hi Mohamad- did either answer work for you? If so, please click the checkmark on one of them to accept it. Otherwise, please let us know if we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question properly. instead of **defaultDate** try **setDate**. As I know there is no onChange event try onSelect method.

```
$('#tgl').daterangepicker({
    setDate: new Date(),//changed defaultDate to setDate.
    arrows:true,
    onSelect: function(){
       $('#frmDate').submit()
    }//removed comma here
 });
```

Comment: Hi Viraths,thanks for your respons. Previous code,i have try with `setDate`. But still not work. and then i try with `defaultDate` but still the same. I just want to set the current date as the default early in my datepicker. So that when I open this page I can filter the data according to the current date.

Comment: Did you try onSelect method instead of onChange