# Differences between defaultDate option vs setDate method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to get my head around using `jQueryUI DatePicker`. One of the main things I must understand is the way a date can be set on page load.

After doing some research, I found 2 different ways to do this:

1. using `defaultDate` option
2. using `setDate` method

The main difference I found out so far is that the `defaultDate` option only sets the value in the datePicker calendar itself.

Whereas the `setDate` method sets both the date in the `input type text` & in the datePicker calendar itself.

One interesting thing is that when using `setDate` method & `defaultDate` option simultaneously, the date set using `setDate` method overrides the value of the date set using the `defaultDate` option.

see http://jsfiddle.net/vb7mu3sf/

Another couple of differences I noticed:

- both accepts the date as a Date type as a parameter (which is very neat) but `defaultDate` option accepts additional types (Number & String).
- `setDate` method can of course be called at anytime on the datePicker

Is there anything else I missed about their differences?

Resources:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate
- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate
- [jQuery-UI datepicker default date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829033/jquery-ui-datepicker-default-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation:

> [**defaultDate**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)
>   Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank.
>
> [**setDate**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)
>   Sets the date for the datepicker.

There is not much left to explain. As mentioned above:

- Setting the `defaultDate` property:

  - Sets the date that is *focused* when the calendar opens and the field is blank.
  - Does not update the field.
  - User has to hit enter or click a date in order to update the field.
- Calling the `setDate` method:

  - Updates the field.
  - Opening the calendar when the field is not-empty causes that date to be *focused* and *selected*.

Possible uses of one technique or the other:

- If the date is a mandatory field -and- there is a default value then use the `setDate` method. This saves two clicks if the user is OK with the pre-entered date.
- Otherwise, use the `defaultDate` to specify the date that is focused should the user choose to activate the datepicker.

---

Notes:

> ... but defaultDate option accepts additional types (Number & String).

Actually, `setDate` accepts all versions of date that `defaultDate` does.

> `setDate` method can of course be called at anytime on the datePicker

Well, the `defaultDate` option can be set anytime as well. For example, if there are two calendars e.g. checkin and checkout and the user chose a checkin date Nov 10, 2014 then you would want to set the `defaultDate` on the other calendar to be Nov 11, 2014.