# How to set the default month and the year of jquery monthpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to set the default month and the year for the jquery monthpicker when page loads.

Below is my code. Currently monthpicker text box is empty when loads.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#monthPicker').datepicker( {
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showButtonPanel: true,
showButtonPanel: true,
dateFormat: 'MM yy',
onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
}
});
});
```

And also, I need to remove the dates from the calendar, I mean I just only need to display the year and month selection options.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490589/how-to-set-the-default-month-and-the-year-of-jquery-monthpicker

Comment: @Wikiti, it won't help much -- the link in your comment points to this very question.

Comment: Sorry, I ment this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829033/jquery-ui-datepicker-default-date My fault!

Comment: @Wikiti Sorry, I couldn't find any solution for my problem there.

Comment: What's "monthpicker"? Isn't that just a regular datepicker ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/62wgkcuv/

Comment: reproducing the problem in a jsfiddle might help us understand it better

Comment: you want to set default date?

Comment: @adeneo thanks, this works. Why don't you put this as an answer? Then I can vote it and accept it as the answer. Btw, how can this implement to stay on the last selected month, year when clicking the calendar for the second time? And, also I need to remove dates from the calendar, keeping only month and year options.

Comment: @ Geeky yes, and also I need to remove date selections from the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a default value when the page loads, just set the date after initializing the datepicker:

```
$(function() {
  $('#monthPicker').datepicker( {
    // ...
  });

  var default_date = new Date(2023, 10, 1);
  $("#monthPicker").datepicker("setDate", default_date);
});
```

Just set whatever date to `default_date`. Rembemer that, in javascripts, months start on `0` (`0` means january, and `11` means december).

Comment: I need to set it as current date.

Comment: Could you explain to me what does *current date* mean to you?

Comment: Today date, now it is fixed. What I need now is removing dates from the calendar, keeping only the month and year selection. And, also I want to implement to stay on the last selected month, year when clicking the calendar for the second time.