# Display C# DateTime in HTML Date Input

Tags: c#, html, datetime

I get a DateTime in SQL Server DataBase and want to display it in Input:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="ExpireDate" id="expiredate" runat="server" value="31/12/2016" style="height: 30px; width: 267px">
```

and here is my C# codes:

```
Medicine med = new Medicine(); 
int a = GridView1.SelectedIndex; 
med.ID = int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[a].Value.ToString()); 
DataProcess bal = new DataProcess(); DataTable dt = bal.getInfo(med)
expiredate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][5]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I put a break point just after the last line , I saw `dt.Rows[0][5]` got "{2017/5/31 0:00:00}" and  `expiredate.Value` got "31/05/2017",but it just shows nothing without error in webpage. And this DateTime record is inserted into DataBase through exactly the same Input, I just don't know how to display it in the same Input when I pull it out from DataBase.

First time to ask, many thanks!

Comment: What is the string value in `dt.Rows[0][5]` at run-time?

Comment: Please edit your questions and put that code in it

Comment: @RyanSearle i just edit my post

Comment: Maybe you could try to change the format of your date in the input to YYYY-MM-DD. Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_date_value.asp for more infos

Comment: When you "inspect" that input in your browser (=find the html for it), do you see your date?

Comment: @LucasDelobelle yes,you're right,this is the KEY!

Comment: @HansKesting yep,I do see it as `31/05/2017`,and `Console` in Inspect shows `The specified value "31/05/2017" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".`. That's it:) thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is the format of html date input and asp.net DateTime doesn't match. Html `date` input displays `mm/dd/yyyy` but the format behind is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Try using `expiredate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][5]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you need vice versa go for; Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are pushing a date inside a input field which is date type. But this won't work. Because html do not support the default value for raw date format. So you have to customize the  date field using a `javascript`. However if ou take any help from `Razor` Html helper then you would be able to do this either not as you are on `.NET framwork`. Easily you can take help from previous answers jQuery[datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829033/jquery-ui-datepicker-default-date), here you can set a default date through javascript, which will show on your input field.